# Error in multiple alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created a SMS Scheduler application, and now I am trying to add multiple scheduling functionality to it. What I have done is once the user clicks a button (named `scheduleSMSButton`), the code collects data, i.e. the phone number, the text and the time at which the sms is to be sent. After this the code creates an object of an inner class, adds the above data to the calling constructor and then starts the `schedule` method.

Here's the code for the scheduleSMSButton:

```
scheduleSMSButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

     //getting the time.
                long difference = targetCal.getTimeInMillis();
     //getting the text.
                String smsData = smsText.getText().toString();
    //getting the phone number.
                String smsAddressee = addressee.getText().toString(); 
    //new object of inner class and start schedule method on that object.       
                new SchedulingInProgress(difference, smsData, smsAddressee).schedule();

}});
```

Here is the inner class I created:

```
private class SchedulingInProgress{

        long timeToTrigger;
        String data;
        String addressee;

        public SchedulingInProgress(long difference, String smsData,
                String smsAddressee) {
            timeToTrigger = difference;
            data = smsData;
            addressee = smsAddressee;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        private void schedule(){
            Intent fireSendSMSClass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                        SendSMS.class);
                fireSendSMSClass.putExtra("smsData", data);
                fireSendSMSClass.putExtra("smsAddressee", addressee);

            PendingIntent pdi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                           0, fireSendSMSClass, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager newManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            newManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToTrigger, pdi);
        }

    }
```

The SendSMSClass does nothing, but sends the message.

The problem I am facing is that if I schedule on sms at time, say at time **19:00 hours** with text **abc**, and another alarm at time **19:02 hours** with text **xyz**; then at 19:00 hours, an sms is sent with the text xyz. And the other sms is not sent at all.

What should I do to fix this bug ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the bug.
The problem was that I was using the same `PendingIntent` again and again, i.e. I used the same `requestCode` (with a defined value of 0). 
The trick was to use a different value each time the `PendingIntent` was instantiated. I used this code to get a new value each time:

```
int requestCode = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then called the `schedule` method like this (I changed the constructor of inner class):

```
new SchedulingInProgress(difference, smsData, smsAddressee, requestCode).schedule();
```

Finally, the `SchedulingInProgress` class looked like this:

```
private class SchedulingInProgress{

        long timeToTrigger;
        String data;
        String addressee;
        int code;

        public SchedulingInProgress(long difference, String smsData,
                String smsAddressee, int requestCode) {
            timeToTrigger = difference;
            data = smsData;
            addressee = smsAddressee;
            code = requestCode;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        private void schedule(){
            Intent fireSendSMSClass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendSMS.class);
            fireSendSMSClass.putExtra("smsData", data);
            fireSendSMSClass.putExtra("smsAddressee", addressee);


            PendingIntent pdi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), code, fireSendSMSClass, 
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            newManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            newManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToTrigger, pdi);
        }

    }
```